# How do I display view states consistently with tabbed view?

Tags: swiftui, enums, tabs

I have a tabbed view where each tab has a struct. I want to display a loading state for each view and then on appear, call the data fetch functions and replace loading state with users. If there are no users returned, I want to return an empty state. But for some reason, if the returned states are different (ex. you have a follower (.loaded state) but no following(.empty state)) then the first state loads fine and the next one loads blank, with no empty state just a blank screen. I have tried separating these into separate view models with different state enums but with no success.

**FollowViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class FollowListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var user: User
    @Published var followingUsers = [User]()
    @Published var followerUsers = [User]()
    @Published var users = [User]()
    private let service = FeedService()
    private let userService = UserService()
    @Published var state: State = .loading

    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
    }
    
    enum State {
        case loading
        case loaded
        case empty
    }
    
    func fetchFollowingList() {
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        
        service.fetchFollowingList(forUid: uid) { users in
            self.followingUsers = users
                .filter({ $0.id != uid })
            
                if self.followingUsers.count > 0 {
                    self.state = .loaded
                } else {
                    self.fetchUsers()
                }
            }
    }
    
    func fetchFollowerList() {
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        
        service.fetchFollowerList(forUid: uid) { users in
            self.followerUsers = users
    
                if self.followerUsers.count > 0 {
                    self.state = .loaded
                } else {
                    self.fetchUsers()
                }
        }
    }
    
    
    func fetchUsers() {
        userService.fetchUsers { users in
            self.users = users
            self.state = .empty
        }
    }
}
```

**FollowListView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FollowListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: FollowListViewModel
    @Binding var followTab: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            UnderlineTabView(["Following", "Followers"], currentTab: $followTab)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Divider()
                        .alignmentGuide(.top) {$0[.top]}
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
            TabView(selection: $followTab) {
                LazyView(FollowingView(viewModel: viewModel, followTab: $followTab).equatable()).tag(0)
                LazyView(FollowerView(viewModel: viewModel, followTab: $followTab).equatable()).tag(1)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .clipped()
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
    }
}
```

**FollowerView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FollowerView: View, Equatable {
    @StateObject var viewModel: FollowListViewModel
    @State var didRefresh = false
    @Binding var followTab: Int

    static func == (lhs: FollowerView, rhs: FollowerView) -> Bool {
        return lhs.didRefresh == rhs.didRefresh
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .loading:
                Spacer()
                ProgressView()
                Spacer()
            case .loaded:
                ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    PullToRefresh(coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
                        viewModel.fetchFollowerList()
                    }
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.followerUsers) { user in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: LazyView(ProfileView(user: user)),
                                label: { ListItemUser(user: user).buttonHidden()                                                                        .padding(.top, 12)
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }.coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
                
            case .empty:
                FollowEmptyStateView(viewModel: viewModel, followTab: $followTab)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchFollowerList()
        }
        
    }
}
```

**FollowingView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FollowingView: View, Equatable {
    @StateObject var viewModel: FollowListViewModel
    @State var didRefresh = false
    @Binding var followTab: Int

    static func == (lhs: FollowingView, rhs: FollowingView) -> Bool {
        return lhs.didRefresh == rhs.didRefresh
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .loading:
                Spacer()
                ProgressView()
                Spacer()
            case .loaded:
                ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    PullToRefresh(coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
                        viewModel.fetchFollowingList()
                    }
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.followingUsers) { user in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: LazyView(ProfileView(user: user)),
                                label: { ListItemUser(user: user).buttonHidden()
                                        .padding(.top, 12)
                                    
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }.coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
                
            case .empty:
                FollowEmptyStateView(viewModel: viewModel, followTab: $followTab)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchFollowingList()
        }
    }
}
```

**FollowEmptyStateView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FollowEmptyStateView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: FollowListViewModel
    @Binding var followTab: Int
    
    var isFollowingTab: Bool { return followTab == 0 }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            Group {
                if viewModel.user.isCurrentUser {
                    EmptyState(
                        title: isFollowingTab ? "Not following anyone yet" : "No followers yet", text: isFollowingTab ? "Here's where you'll find the people who you follow." : "Here's where you'll find the people who follow you.",
                        image: "follow-empty", isSmallImage: true, isLongText: true
                    )
                } else {
                    EmptyState(
                        title: isFollowingTab ? "Not following anyone yet" : "No followers yet", text: isFollowingTab ? "\(viewModel.user.firstName) does not follow anyone yet." : "\(viewModel.user.firstName) does not have any followers yet.",
                        image: "follow-empty", isSmallImage: true, isLongText: true
                    )
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            if viewModel.user.isCurrentUser {
                Divider()
                
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Suggested for you")
                        .font(Font.body)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    //random 10 users
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.users.shuffled().prefix(10)) { user in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: LazyView(ProfileView(user: user)),
                                label: { ListItemUser(user: user).buttonHidden()
                                        .padding(.top, 12)
                                    
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `View` Identity is managed by an invisible underlying system all your conformance to `Equatable` is likely interfering, remove all of that, The SwiftUI tutorials and "Demystify SwiftUI" can help you shed some light. Also, `StateObject` is a source of truth with storage in the underlying system it is used for initializing and should be marked `private` use `ObservedObject` for passing around.

Comment: Your code seems to come from an experienced developer in some other language or framework. SwiftUI is not like others it does a lot of the work for you and you have to adapt to it for your app to be efficient and seamless.

Comment: @loremipsum thanks I am about to watch the demystify swiftui video. I removed equatable from both views but i'm still having the same problem